# Updating a resource in Vue JS reactively?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I want to save form data to my backend every time the user changes the data on the page, (ideally with a timeout to wait until the user has stopped making changes and then save it).

I've thought of a few ways of handling this. I could put change events on all the fields to do so. I could also try and use a computed variable and add a call to the set method every time the object is set but this seems overly complex.

I haven't seen many examples of people doing this with Vue JS. Is there a clear way to do it? Is there a way to simply say upon the data object changing, run the following function?

Comment: search for the `watch` method in vuejs guide.

Comment: @YerkoPalma is that the best way to do things though. I looked at it and honestly wasn't sure if that wouldn't produce the same issues as a computed especially if the object I'm watching has nested objects?

Comment: Well about the reactivity, both methods work without much problems in Vue. Computed props are easier, if you prefer watch, keep the `deep` option to `true` so you also track nested properties in objects. Vuejs internally has optimizations about this (check [this](https://github.com/footballradar/VueReactPerf) performance comparison with react and read the blog post)

Comment: Now the part of _updating a resource_ is hard to optimize because is a call to your server constantly, definitly not efficient. I would use a timeOut in js to define an `autosave` ever X minutes. Or I would use Vuex to keep a state of my app and save every couple of minutes or even hours, but a large range of time.

Comment: @YerkoPalma my thoughts was generally to use a timeout of say 10 seconds. I'd stringify the object and hash it, then wait for the timeout, if the object still produces the same hash then it should update otherwise it will just give up as the timeout function should have been triggered again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `debounce` attribute on your inputs:

https://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#debounce

Then you can use the `watch()` method as Yerko suggested.  The attributes in Vue won't be updated until after the timeout, at which point your `watch` function will fire.

If that isn't strong enough, you'd have to save the `setTimeout` variable and then cancel it and restart it in your `watch` function using `clearTimeout`.  This isn't as complex as it sounds, just an extra variable and a deep watch function.